# Retrieving sub directory name and using it to call function in linux . Every time calling fun1 with the same sub directory name

Tags: c++, linux, dirent.h

Suppose inside main directory (A) i have only 2 sub directories B and C:

```
A: 
  -B
  -C
```

I want to achieve following functionality:

> Calling getLangDir function the first time, then I should be able to call `fun1(0, A)` only if I called `getLangDir` function for the second time, then I should be able to call `fun1(1,B)` only.

In `fun1` I am using foldernum value and `entity->d_name` string.

Here in first and second case I am calling like `fun1(0,A)`, `fun1(1,A)` respectively.

NOTE : Here Using dirent header file. Also not call `getLangDir` recursively as I want first level subdirectory .

```
int foldernum=0; //global variable
void getLangDir(std::string dirname) {

    DIR* dir = opendir(dirname.c_str());
    if (dir == NULL) return;
    std::cout<<"Reading directory in:  "<< dirname<<std::endl;

    struct dirent* entity;
    entity = readdir(dir);

    while (entity != NULL)
    {
        if (entity->d_type == DT_DIR && strcmp(entity->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(entity->d_name, "..") != 0)
        {  
            if(foldernum==0){
                std::string str(entity->d_name);
                fun1(foldernum,str);
                foldernum++;
                break;
            }
           else if(foldernum==1){
                std::string str(entity->d_name);
                fun1(foldernum,str);
                foldernum++;
                break;
            }
           else
                return;
        }
        entity = readdir(dir);
    }

   closedir(dir);
}
```

Comment: The overall design using a global variable is very poor. Don't use global variables for maintaining state in a function. BTW it's absolutely unclear what you're trying to achieve, both cases `foldernum==0` and `foldernum==1` do the same thing in your code.

Comment: Please [edit] and add some code that shows how you intend to call `getLangDir` along with the output you expect. But anyway, this is probably an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you want.

Your overall approach is wrong because maintaining state of functions using global variables is very poor practice, it's hard to debug and it's error prone. And because the whole approach is wrong anyway because you should approach this as follows:

1. put all filenames of the A directory (B and C in your example) in a `std::vector`.
2. for each string in the vector: call `fun1(foldernum ,element);`

Code outline:

```
std::vector<std::string> files;

GetFilesFromDirectory("A", files);

for (auto foldernum = 0; foldernum < files.size(); foldernum++)
{
  fun1(foldernum, files[foldernum]);
}

void GetFilesFromDirectory(std::string dirname, std::vector & files)
{
  // fill the files vector with filenames of dirname
  DIR* dir = opendir(dirname.c_str());
  ... // 4-5 five more lines you should be able to write on your own
      // hint: use files.push_back(entity->d_name) at some point
}
```

You might need to add some error handling.

Comment: A and B directory I  have  taken as example. At run time I will read these dir, out of 20  folder only 2 will be present in A dir.
This getLangDir ( ) fun is getting called  2 times from another function. and first  time I want to read  "A" , first  sub-directory and using that call fun1 . second time when getLangDir ( ) fun is getting called from another fucntion . I will   read second sub directory and call fun1. will your approach work  here ?  I don't  want to get  both directory   while call getLangDir  ( ) fun ,first time. Sorry I am  not much expert ,have patience with me.

Comment: @anshugang this approach is wrong, don't do it.